# How can I include the "name" field from an HTML form in the mailto: subject line?

Tags: html, forms, mailto

I have an HTML form that I would like to have the ?subject on the mailto pull the name field from the form on submit. Something like this:

```
mailto:"emailaddress@domainname.com?subject=contact submission from 'name field'"
```

I have searched the site and the web but have not found a solution that will work.

Comment: Can you show your full code? The vague answer is: use js to get the value in the name field, then insert it int your mailto string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue! Using Advanced Custom Fields on a WordPress site, I can create the mailto and use the get_field function and populate the subject like I need to. It also allows me to populate the e-mail and any other field I need to from information collected via the site.